# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Service when executing Jest test

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I added `StaticContentService` to my `UserService` class as a dependency. Then, I tried to run my jest test, but following error is occuring.

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument StaticContentService at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context.`

Following is my user service class.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
    private staticContentService: StaticContentService,
  ) {}}
```

I have mocked and added StaticContentService and StaticContentRepository to my testing module as follows.

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          load: [AppConfig],
        }),
      ],
      controllers: [StageReviewController],
      providers: [
        PrismaService,
        { provide: StaticContentRepository, useClass: MockStaticContentRepository },
        { provide: StaticContentService, useClass: MockStaticContentService },
        UserService,
        UserRepository,
    }).compile();
```

Anyone knows how to fix the mentioned dependency error at the top? Any help would be great.

Comment: how did you import the `StaticContentService` class on both files (user.service and the spec one)

Comment: Found the issue :). I was using absolute path to import StaticContentService. After changing it to relative path, problem solved.